# hung ruby process (ruby 1.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [x86_64-linux]

I have a ruby batch job that the last 2 nights in a row has hung up at about the same time.

The weird thing is when I do a kill -QUIT on the process it frees it up and continues processing.

Here is the stack when I send the SIGQUIT:

```
Wed Mar 23 2011 11:07:55 SignalException: SIGQUIT: SELECT * FROM `influencers` WHERE      (`influencers`.`external_id` = 199884972)  LIMIT 1
Wed Mar 23 2011 11:07:55 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record /connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-  2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:323:in `execute'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 /gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:608:in `select'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:661:in `find_by_sql'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1548:in `find_every'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1505:in `find_initial'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:613:in `find'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1900:in `find_by_twitter_id'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/app/models/influencer.rb:148:in `add_follower'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/app/models/influencer.rb:93:in `sync_follower_list'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/app/models/influencer.rb:91:in `each'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/app/models/influencer.rb:91:in `sync_follower_list'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/twitter_helper.rb:379:in `retrieve_followers_of_competitors'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/twitter_helper.rb:372:in `each'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/twitter_helper.rb:372:in `retrieve_followers_of_competitors'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/vendor/gems/will_paginate-2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:369:in `method_missing_without_paginate'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `each'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:369:in `method_missing_without_paginate'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/vendor/gems/will_paginate-2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/twitter_helper.rb:370:in `retrieve_followers_of_competitors'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/twitter_helper.rb:42:in `retrieve_twitter_data'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/tasks/fetch_data.rake:19:in `fetch_data'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/tasks/fetch_data.rake:11:in `each'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/tasks/fetch_data.rake:11:in `fetch_data'/u/apps/myapp/releases/20110323011051/lib/tasks/fetch_data.rake:128/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'/usr/bin/rake:19
```

I suspect that from looking at the code im getting some kind of deadlock on the rails logger. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot. Maybe something to do with rails logger folding. Not sure why this would start in last couple days....

Comment: Rule #4: Format your stack traces.

Comment: Hi Zabba, can you explain rule #4 I dont see anything in the faq about this, I formatted my stack using the code markup so it would scroll. What format would please you?

Comment: Rule #4.7 says that stack traces look good when each method call is displayed on a separate line. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you use logrotate on your logs, but it could be that the logs get rotated and Rails.logger can't write anything any more. Doing a `kill -QUIT` would re-open the log file and continue processing.

Comment: Good idea, I had issues with logrotate in the past causing similar issue, but I think I have disabled it. I am using rails logger to rotate: config.logger = Logger.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log", 'daily') . You think this could be same issue? I guess I can turn it off for now and see if that fixes it.